# Python Touples - Keep only the largest value if First item is found duplicate

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have a python list of touples like this:

```
touple = [('Northwest Airlines', 93), 
         ('Northwest Airlines', 81), 
         ('Southwest Airlines', 79), 
         ('NorthWestern', 77), 
         ('NorthWestern', 69), 
         ('Southwest Airlines', 69)]
```

Several of these items are duplicate. I want to keep only unique Touples having the largest value as the 2nd item.

The output I want to achieve is like this:

```
processed_touple = [('Northwest Airlines', 93),                      
                   ('Southwest Airlines', 79), 
                   ('NorthWestern', 77)]
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dic = {}

for item in touple:
    name, score = item
    if name not in dic:
        dic[name] = score
    else:
        if score > dic[name]:
            dic[name] = score
        

print(list(dic.items()))
```

output:

```
[('Northwest Airlines', 93), ('Southwest Airlines', 79), ('NorthWestern', 77)]
```

Comment: instead of `dic.get(name, None) == None` consider `name in dic`

Comment: ...and `elif` instead of `else if` ;)

Comment: @gog think else: if is more logical here

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp = dict((y, x) for x, y in touple)

my_dict = dict()
for val, key in tmp.items():
    if key not in my_dict.keys():
        my_dict[key] = val
    else:
        if my_dict[key] < val:
            my_dict[key] = val
```

Output: my_dict

```
 {'Northwest Airlines': 93, 'Southwest Airlines': 79, 'NorthWestern': 77}
```

Comment: you don't need this `tmp` dict, just iterate the subject directly

Comment: If I loop directly it removes the duplicate key